# Maria DB - Prevent removal of trailing white space in where clause

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB version 10.3.22 and 10.3.23

I have a table with column name entries like these. The second entry contains trailing spaces. Datatype of the column is Varchar(50)

```
"John"
"John          "
```

I want the below query to return **only the first entry**, but it returns both entries. Seems like internally, it's doing the trim while comparing. Any way to perform the exact match

```
Select name from <table> where name="John";
```

Similarly, the below query should not return any rows as I'm trying to match with extra space, but it outputs two rows. Some behind the scene trimming is happening. Need to either disable it or anyway to do the exact match

```
Select name from <table> where name="John  ";
```

Comment: Consider whether you really want to store trailing spaces. This is going to be a pain to work with.

Comment: Understand, but that's the requirement. We need to store as both with and without spaces have it's own business meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `BINARY` option to compare exactly rather than as strings.

```
Select name from <table> where BINARY name="John";
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to go through MariaDB documentation on available string functions and similar items. Good it works as expected